# Using Serpent or TwoFish C# example?

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, bouncycastle, twofish

For the past week, I've been looking for how to impliment either Serpent or TwoFish into C#.

I've come across [bouncycastle](http://bouncycastle.org), which has no documentation on those, and [this code project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2593/A-C-implementation-of-the-Twofish-cipher), which also doesnt have documentation, or a clear example.

I was wondering, if anyone could provide me with an example of Serpent or Twofish, using bouncycastle or that codeproject article. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can get something from a post of mine [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34971272/writing-php-mcrypt-twofish-for-c-sharp-bouncycastle?noredirect=1#comment57687765_34971272). I have an example of TwoFish in c# using BouncyCastle. It is not complete will all the alternatives but will work. It will encrypt and decrypt its own messages but I'm struggling with getting it to be cross platform with mcrypt.